# getting value of nested JSON with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have very little experience working with jSON

My problem is getting the value from nested arrays.

I've tried  `for loops` and `.each()` but for some reason it never works as expected.

I'm trying to access the `artname.artists.name` for each `artname` object.

I can console.log it by doing `console.log(data.artname[0].artists.name);`

I've tried to use for loop inside .each();

Can someone help me out here?

Here is a sample of may code

```
var i;
var actors = data.artname;
var text = "";
for (i=0; i <actors.length; i++){
 text += actors[i] + "<br>";
console.log(actors.name);
}
```

I can access the `role` from `artname` but I'm not able to go deeper and access the actors name from `artists`

```
$.each(data.artname, function(i, arts){
$("#arts").append( '<li>' + 'Role:' + arts.role + " " + '</li>');  

   $.each(arts.artists, function(j,actor){ 


     $("#actor").append( '<li>' + 'Actor:' + actor.name  + '</li>'); // gives undefined


   });

});
```

Here is a part of the JSON file.

```
    "data": {
"artname" : [ {
    "nr" : 123,
    "role" : "john booth",
    "artists" : {
      "nr" : 81,
      "name" : "Tom Tomson",
      "birthday" : "1954-01-11",
      "allowed" : true,
      "printForm" : "Tom Hanks (11.01.1954-15.04.1999)"
    },
    "profession" : {
      "name" : "actors"
    }
  }, 
  "artname" : [ {
      "nr" : 153,
      "role" : "clair luv",
      "artists" : {
        "nr" : 141,
        "name" : "Ron Ronson",
        "birthday" : "1924-03-11",
        "allowed" : true,
        "printForm" : "Ron Ronsson (11.03.1924-11.04.1959)"
      },
      "profession" : {
        "name" : "actors"
      }
    }, 
    "artname" : [ {
        "nr" : 423,
        "role" : "john booth",
        "artists" : {
          "nr" : 64,
          "name" : "Jane Joe",
          "birthday" : "1974-01-11",
          "allowed" : true,
          "printForm" : "Jane Doe (11.01.1974-15.04.1999)"
        },
        "profession" : {
          "name" : "actors"
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: The JSON data structure is invalid. Could you please correct the sample data? You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$.each(data.artname, function(i, arts){
    $.each(arts.artists, function(j,actor){
```

you loop over *arts.artists*. But this is a Object, not a Array. Your variable *j* will become the key/attribute-name and *actor* become the value:

```
$.each(arts.artists, function(j,actor){ 
  console.log(j+': '+actor);
}
```

try this and rethink what do you want to get instead :)

When you only need the name try this one:

```
$.each(data.artname, function(i, arts){
    $("#arts").append( '<li>' + 'Role:' + arts.role + " " + '</li>');  
    console.log(arts.artists.name);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, now I'm able see nr, name, birthday, allowed, printform for all actors. I have no Idea how to fish just the name from it.

Comment: try arts.artists.name but not inside the second for-each-loop. Remove this for-each-loop *$.each(arts.artists, function(j,actor){  ... }*

Comment: I get your point, but what I need is the name from the `arts.artists`  as in   "artists" : {
        "nr" : 141,
        "name" : "Ron Ronson",                                                                                 I  managed to display the Role by my self :)

Comment: The last part of @Marcus' answer shows how the artist's name can be accessed. Doesn't it work for you, @codegirl?

Comment: Then please correct the sample JSON data structure in your question. The brackets are not matching.